# Target blank (open in new window) for click track in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

This code successfully tracks clicks in Google Analytics.  However, despite target="_blank" in the link, it doesn't open in a new window or tab.

Is there a simple tweak to the GA script to open in a separate window or tab?

(I just noticed a similar question was asked way back in 2014, that suggested deleting the callback (hitCallback) in the js; Hoping there is a fresh answer?)

In the header:

```
<script>
/**
* Function that captures a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
* using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
*/
var captureOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}
   });
}
</script>
```

In the content:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://example.com" onclick="captureOutboundLink('https://example.com'); return false;">Test for click to Example</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `'hitCallback': function(){document.location = url;}`
to `'hitCallback': function(){window.open(url);}`
eg

```
<script>
/**
* Function that captures a click on an outbound link in Analytics.
* This function takes a valid URL string as an argument, and uses that URL string
* as the event label. Setting the transport method to 'beacon' lets the hit be sent
* using 'navigator.sendBeacon' in browser that support it.
*/
var captureOutboundLink = function(url) {
   ga('send', 'event', 'outbound', 'click', url, {
     'transport': 'beacon',
     'hitCallback': function(){window.open(url);}
   });
}
</script>
```